# Блог на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Как можно добавить в админку Wordpress стандартный пункт "Записи" и, соответственно, чтобы были пункты "Редактировать запись", "Добавить новую" и т.д., и весь стандартный функционал этого меню соответственно?

Comment: В админке WP по умолчанию уже есть пункт "Записи" и все перечисленные возможности

Comment: В моей нету, в том то и проблема. Тема нестандартная